# ¿Cómo convertir parte del nombre de un archivo en una variable para añadirla a un dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Bajé algunos dataframe de una plataforma y el identificador no está en el archivo, sino en una parte del nombre del archivo. Necesito "sacar" esa parte del nombre para crear una nueva columna en el archivo con esa información.

[image: Imagen de una parte de los archivos]

Este es un ejemplo de los archivos. Necesito sacar del nombre la parte de los números y agregarlos como una columna dentro de ese mismo archivo.

Hasta ahora no tengo ninguna pista de cómo hacerlo. Lo intenté con otra variable pero solo lo pude sacar manualmente así:

```
#Adición de Código estación a HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025090
`HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025090` <- cbind (`HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025090`, "CodigoEstacion" = 51025090)
```

El resultado debe ser una matriz conjunta de todos los documentos, pero que los elementos correspondientes a cada archivo tenga su respectivo código. De esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(que sería el ejemplo de la otra variable, correspondiente al archivo HRA2_MEDIA_D@11105020. Solo una parte)

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si el/la usuario/a que realizó la edición también sos vos, solicitá [combinar tus cuentas](/contact).

Answer (score 0):

Si partes de la base que tiene un vector con todos los nombres de archivo y que estos respetan el mismo formato como el que muestras, algo como esto:

```
archivos <- c('HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025090',
              'HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025091',
              'HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025092')
```

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
estaciones <- cbind(CodigoEstacion=sapply(strsplit(archivos, '@'), FUN=function(x) {x[[2]]}))

data.frame(archivos, estaciones)

               archivos CodigoEstacion
1 HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025090       51025090
2 HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025091       51025091
3 HRA2_MEDIA_D@51025092       51025092
```

Con `strsplit(archivos, '@')` dividimos las dos partes del nombre y con `sapply` aplicamos `FUN=function(x) {x[[2]]})` con la que extraemos solo la segunda cadena que tiene el `CodigoEstacion`